# How to execute async lua code with rlua-async?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-actix

I'm trying to run/script my existing rust async code with [rlua-async](https://crates.io/crates/rlua-async). Sadly it is not well documented and has no examples but I have prevailed in getting my async functions defined but I have trouble getting my lua code executed in an async way.

I have created a minimal repository to reproduce the problem [here](https://github.com/arturh85/rlua-async-example)

```
use rlua::{Lua};
use rlua_async::{ChunkExt, ContextExt};

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() {
    let lua_code = "my.asyncfunc(42)";
    let lua = Lua::new();

    lua.context(|lua_ctx| {
        let globals = lua_ctx.globals();
        let map_table = lua_ctx.create_table().unwrap();
        map_table
            .set(
                "asyncfunc",
                lua_ctx
                    .create_async_function(
                        |_ctx,
                         param:
                            u32
                        | async move {
                            println!("async function called {}", param);
                            Ok(())
                        }).unwrap()).unwrap();

        globals.set("my", map_table).unwrap();
    });

    lua.context(|lua_context| async move {
        let chunk = lua_context
            .load(&lua_code);
        chunk.exec_async(lua_context).await.unwrap();
    })
        .await;
    println!("finished");
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:28:31
   |
28 |       lua.context(|lua_context| async move {
   |  __________________------------_^
   | |                  |          |
   | |                  |          return type of closure is impl Future
   | |                  has type `LuaContext<'1>`
29 | |         let chunk = lua_context
30 | |             .load(&lua_code);
31 | |         chunk.exec_async(lua_context).await.unwrap();
32 | |     })
   | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

I really don't get what the error is trying to tell me and there is no helpful tips or even documentation linked.

The closure is somehow different from the closure body and needs lifetime annotations? But why and how...?

EDIT: if I instead call the code without async like this:

```
lua.context(|lua_context| {
    let chunk = lua_context.load(&lua_code);
    chunk.exec().unwrap();
});
```

it compiles but I get the following panic on runtime:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first', C:\Users\ahallmann\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\scoped-tls-1.0.0\src\lib.rs:168:9
```

Everything works fine if I define the function with create_function.

Comment: Is that the full error message? If not, could you post it?

Comment: Yes it is, other than 
error: aborting due to previous error
error: could not compile `rlua-async-example`

Comment: Why don’t you remove `async move` and just use normal `exec`? The `context` method doesn’t expect a future, so if you are intent on using async, I *think* you would need to use something like a `block_on` method from your async runtime. I’m not sure how async is supposed to work with `rlua`.

Comment: If I do that I get the following error at runtime: thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first', C:\Users\ahallmann\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\scoped-tls-1.0.0\src\lib.rs:168:9

Comment: This might be a bug in one of your dependencies. Can you set `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` and post the full backtrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the kind help of the author of rlua-async.
The issue is with the actix-rt itself as it requires 'static lifetimes for the block_on call.

It works fine if you use either futures or tokio instead:

```
        tokio::runtime::Runtime::new()
            .unwrap()
            .block_on(chunk.exec_async(ctx))
```

See https://github.com/actix/actix-net/issues/201
or
https://github.com/Ekleog/rlua-async/issues/1 for further information.